# Strange icon keeps appearing at the temple

Tags: prince-of-persia-2008

Everytime I go to the temple in Prince of Persia 2008, a strange icon keeps appearing at the bottom left of the screen. It keeps blinking and seems to be of two images - the Prince and Elika. I can't figure out what exactly the icon means. I tried talking to her but it's just normal banter. Any idea what that blinking icon means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're describing is the "Elika has something to say" icon. As I recall, there is a *lot* of banter in that area. Try to keep talking to her and see if she says something different each time. If Elika has run out of things to say, she'll start repeating herself (or maybe she won't even respond when you hit the button--I don't remember exactly).

If you find the dialog tedious, you can always just ignore it by not hitting the button. Anything *really* important to the story is in the cutscenes, and other important stuff is mostly in the first few things she says about an area.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have come across a situation where you need to talk to Elika, or you must select a destination to proceed forward. It even happens after a boss fight, when new areas get unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an indication that the game is saving your progress up to that point; this sort of blinking icon visual sign has been used as an autosave indicator in several other games.

Comment: Just had a look at a random video of the game starting up on youtube, the autosaving icon definitely doesn't look like what Mugen's describing, it's just a circular arrow sort of thing.

Comment: @Chad Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification, maaaaaan.